# Hope you are doing well

Tags: conversation

I am going to a business trip and my boss wrote an email saying

> Hope you are doing well.

What does that mean? And how to reply?

Comment: When and where did they say it? Did they or you say anything before this? Was it written? Details, please. **In general**, you don't need to do anything, apart from thanking them for asking - "Thanks for asking"

Comment: This has been [edited](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/24037/revisions). I have voted to leave closed because: it is primarily opinion-based and there are too many appropriate answers for the SE format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is in a letter, it is usually a simple common courtesy in letter writing, and does not warrant a specific response.  Traditionally, (and I'm talking 17th/18th Century) the correct response to something like this is "Hope you are doing well" i.e. a complete copy of what was said.  Saying "I'm fine, thanks" was originally  considered bad manners.

But anyway, if it was spoken in modern terms, it's just a simple "hope you're good" or "hope you're ok" and you can reply with something honest "Great, thanks! or "Crap, been better." :)